# Java while loop not breaking after "break" statement

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopsEndingRemembering {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // program in this project exercises 36.1-36.5
        // actually this is just one program that is split in many parts

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
       int input = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

       while(true){

           if(input == -1){
               break;
           }

         }



       System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");


    }
}
```

The user should be able to put in multiple numbers until -1 is reached. Once its reached it should break the loop and print the last line.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put

```
 System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
 int input = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
```

into your loop, else it will never get new user input

Comment: That was it, thanks! So whenever i use a variable within a loop the variable has to be declared within the loop? Sorry pretty beginner level questions.

Comment: It does not need to be declared inside the loop, but in your code it has no purpose outside the loop.  The key thing is that the new value has to be obtained within the loop

Answer (score 0):

You need call scanner inside loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LoopsEndingRemembering {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 while(true){
           Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
           int input = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
               if(input == -1){
                   break;
               }
             }
           System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you instantiate your scanner within the loop?

Comment: updated @ScaryWombat appreciate you for the notifying me